# Clojure substring with negative index

Tags: clojure

I want to implement a clojure function that will return the substring in a given string, 
Given a string

```
(def mystring "clojurestring")
(subs mystring 0 3)  ;=> "clo"
```

I want to be able to use a negative index to get sub-string starting from the last character i.e

```
(subs mystring -13 3) ;=> "clo"
```

I also think

```
(subs mystring -9 7) ;=> "ure"
```

The format for getting the substring in clojure is
    (subs 'string' start end)

`start`. Starting offset, negative offset counts from end of  string.Parameter is a positive or negative number.

`end`. Parameter is an integer greater than zero

so far I have tried without any luck, I don't know if this is possible

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @zero323, I'm counting on you for this one. Thanks!

Comment: just for exercise or for string-manip in development? if latter [this](https://github.com/expez/superstring) may be of interest - especially [`slice`](https://github.com/expez/superstring/blob/master/src/superstring/core.clj#L86)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: You problem is underspecified.  Is the third parameter the index to substring to, or a count of letters?

Comment: @verdammelt I tried `(subs mystring (- (count mystring) 3))` that the much I can think for the solution.

Comment: The argument lists for  `subs` are `[start] ` and `[start end]`, not `[start length]`. Since your example, `(subs mystring 0 3)`, starts at `0`, there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If start is negative, you simply want to subtract from the length of the string. If I understand your requirement correctly:

```
(defn subs* [s start end]
  (if (neg? start)
    (subs s (+ (.length s) start) end)
    (subs s start end)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn my-subs [st from end]
  (let [f (if (neg? from)
               (+ (count st) from)
               from)]
    (subs st f end)))

(my-subs "clojurestring" -9 7)
;"ure"
```